# can't sending logs using NLog network target

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to write logs to Logststash on a remote machine using NLog. Here is the configuration file:

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="Network" address="http://52.160.89.158:8080" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Off course the data isn't been written to Logstash...
However I successfully write messages to Logstash using simpe HTTP POST message that I generated in Postman meaning I have no connection issues... Any suggestions?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version and check the internal log.